# How to override location directive in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a main Nginx conf file `/etc/nginx/main.conf`as:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset UTF-8;

    include /etc/nginx/available.d/application.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
}
```

Where `/etc/nginx/available.d/application.conf` looks like

```
...
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
}
...
```

*Note that I am allowed to add/override settings with a conf file under `/etc/nginx/default.d/` only.*

And I want to override the `index` directive of `/etc/nginx/main.conf` and `location` directive of `/etc/nginx/available.d/application.conf` (as shown below).

I have created a new conf file `/etc/nginx/default.d/custom.conf` as:

```
index app.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$query_string;
}
```

`index` overriding is working fine but the `location` directive is throwing an error:

> nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/default.d/custom.conf

How would you overide the `location` directive from custom file in this case?

Comment: You can't have two identical locations. Why not to just modify the `/etc/nginx/available.d/application.conf` file instead?

Comment: that's the problem. is there any workaround?

Comment: You can use `location = /index.php { rewrite ^ /app.php last; }`, but this way you'll never be able to access the `index.php`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks will check this approach.

Comment: One more clarification. The above applies only for `index.php` file in the webroot directory, any other `index.php` in any nested directory will remain accessible. Remove that `index app.php;` line, you don't need it, but it can break some other parts of the site.